# Google script doesn´t work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, google-visualization

Other browsers like IE, Chrome, Edge work properly, is it possible to be fixed on Firefox?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['gauge'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGauge);

        var gaugeOptions = {
            min: 0, max: 100, minorTicks: 5
        };
        var gauge;

        function drawGauge() {
            gaugeData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            gaugeData.addColumn('number', 'Temp');
            gaugeData.addRows(1);
            gaugeData.setCell(0, 0, document.getElementById('LabelT').innerText);
            gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
            gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
        } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Robert Longson - Bingo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerText is not standardised and you shouldn't use it. IE and Chrome have slightly different implementations because of that. Firefox does not have an implementation of innerText yet.

The nearest standards based equivalent supported everywhere is textContent.